# How to seperate materials from 2 meshes that are duplicates?

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

I have 2 spheres (eyeballs), one is a duplicate of the other, they are connected as one object. They share the same material.

I would like to draw on both of them individually but when I paint on one it paints the identical strokes to the other as well. How do I make their materials independent of each other. It's acting like it has a mirror modifier on it.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "connected as one object"? Do they share the same mesh data block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the duplicated object is linked (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, the new object shares the same mesh as the original), go into the *Material* panel, click on the *Link* button and choose *Object* instead of *Data* so that the object shares only the mesh, not the same material. Now you can give another material to your new object.

[image]

If you're talking about a duplicated object that is not linked (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), by default the copy will have a new material. But note that even though it's a new material, if in this material you use an *Image Texture*, it will be the same image in both the 2 materials. If you want the copy to keep the same material go in the *Preferences > Editing > Objects > Copy and Duplicate* and disable *Material*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for illustrating these 2 methods, it's much appreciated on my beginner Blender journey. Being such a newb at this I didn't realize that I had to separate my objects first, once I did that I was able to add new materials to each.

Comment: You don't have to separate them if you want them to share the same mesh, but if you also want to separate their meshes, go into Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data